# Rails Apartment Tenant LocalJumpError switch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apartment-gem

I m creating a tenant when I click on a button in a view. The tenant is well create but when I try to switch to this tenant just after I have this error:
LocalJumpError in EntreprisesController#create_tenant - no block given (yield). Thanks for any help

My controller:

```
# creation du tenant dans apartement
  def create_tenant
    Apartment::Tenant.create(params[:id])
    Apartment::Tenant.switch(params[:id])
 #   redirect_to entreprise_path(enterprise_id: params[:entreprise])
  end
```

My view:

```
  <div class="col-md-2">
          <%= link_to "add new tenant", create_tenant_entreprise_path(id: entreprise.subdmain), method: :post  %>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you tell what is `switch` in `Apartment::Tenant.switch(params[:id])` I have never seen this kind of code yet. I was thinking of a switch method in Tennant controller but not sure at all.

Comment: Sorry didn't see it was Apartment gem related. Not an easy gem to work with as a Rails beginner, especially if you have a User domain working with Devise. You should watch this video which seems pretty good https://youtu.be/L5y72hfIT_M . The video says that basically you shouldn't redirect, but let your user type his address like `newtenant.myapp.com` to get to the very tenant. In your case your are missing the block. Apartment documentation says you can use `switch!` instead. It should work then.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the switch at all, just redirect to the proper url.

If you have set a subdomain apartment, then you have to redirect to that subdomain. Apartment elevator will do the switch automatically from the url as is always the case.

`switch` is meant to be used with a block. There's a `switch!` that might work in your case too, but this is not the way to go unless you have some very specific edge case, which I honestly can't think of.